# jQuery being ignored within an if statement. Console log shows that the if statement is being executed

Tags: jquery, json, for-loop

I have two blocks of json one that is self defined and one that is brought from the server.  The way that it works is that I have a for loop which runs through the static json and appends form html to the window based on what's there, it simultaneously adds values to those forms if those values exist on the server based on the 2nd json object that is brought from the server.  So when field.jsonName == type it startes another if statement that looks at the values json object.  If that object is == 2 it should change the value of that select box.  It does log in the console 'type=2'

I've found a lot of information on different ways to change the value of a select box and I've tried all of them I can think of but I'm still not getting the results I need.  It's as though the entire statement is ignored for some reason.  My code is below

For reference here is the larger portion of the code

```
        // Add default Fields to Fieldset
        addDefaultFields: function(fieldset) {
            for (f in defaults.fields) {
                // get field info - if quizJSON exists, use quizJSON data
                field     = defaults.fields[f];
                inputName = field.q.replace(/\W/g,'');
                required  = field.required ? defaults.requiredString : '';
                nameAndId = 'name="' + inputName + '" id="' + inputName + '"';
                option1 = '<option value=' +field.value1+ '>' + field.option1 + '</option>';
                option2 = '<option value=' +field.value2+ '>' + field.option2 + '</option>';
                option3 = '<option value=' +field.value3+ '>' + field.option3 + '</option>';
                option4 = '<option value=' +field.value4+ '>' + field.option4 + '</option>';
                option5 = '<option value=' +field.value5+ '>' + field.option5 + '</option>';
                option6 = '<option value=' +field.value6+ '>' + field.option6 + '</option>';

                if (quizValues != null) {

                    //Prevent Passing score from resetting when editing a quiz

                    if (field.jsonName == 'percent'){
                        value = plugin.formHelper.htmlspecialchars(quizValues.info[field.jsonName] * 100);
                    } else if (field.jsonName == 'type') { console.log(quizValues.info.type);
                        if(quizValues.info.type == '0') {
                            $("#QuizType").val('0');
                        } else if (quizValues.info.type == '1') {
                            $("#QuizType").val('1');
                        } else if (quizValues.info.type == '2') {
                            $("#QuizType").val('2'); console.log('type = 2');
                        } else if (quizValues.info.type == '3') {
                            $("#QuizType").val('3');
                        } else if (quizValues.info.type == '4') {
                            $("#QuizType").val('4');
                        } else  {
                            $("#QuizType").val('5');
                        }
                    }

                    else{

                        value = plugin.formHelper.htmlspecialchars(quizValues.info[field.jsonName]); }
                } else {
                    value = '';
                }
```

Here is the portion I'm struggling with

```
 else if (field.jsonName == 'type') { console.log(quizValues.info.type);
                        if(quizValues.info.type == '0') {
                            $("#QuizType").val('0');
                        } else if (quizValues.info.type == '1') {
                            $("#QuizType").val('1');
                        } else if (quizValues.info.type == '2') {
                            $("#QuizType").val('2'); console.log('type = 2');
                        } else if (quizValues.info.type == '3') {
                            $("#QuizType").val('3');
                        } else if (quizValues.info.type == '4') {
                            $("#QuizType").val('4');
                        } else  {
                            $("#QuizType").val('5');
                        }
                    }
```

The first console.log when it enters the else if field.name == 'percent' shows that the value of type = 2.  The second fires as expected stating that type = 2.  But nothing else happens.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. When do you want the second `else if` block execute? It will never execute if the `jsonName` is `percent`.

Comment: All those if else statements looks like a perfect spot for an associative array.

Comment: Basically I have two blocks of json one that is self defined and one that is brought from the server.  The way that it works is the for loop runs through the static json and appends form html to the window based on what's there, it simultaneously adds values to those forms if those values exist on the server based on the 2nd json object that is brought from the server.  So when field.jsonName == type it startes another if statement that looks at the values json object.  If that object is == 2 it should fire the value change.  It does fire the console.log('type=2') portion.

Comment: What do you mean by "fire the value change". Do you mean that it should change the value?

Comment: yes sorry if that wasn't clear.  And I know the code sucks, I didn't program it, it's part of a wordpress plugin that I'm trying to modify to better suit my needs

Answer (score 0):

You're code is not very clear and it's not very evident as to what it is you want to accomplish. But you can cut down the complexity (and possibility of bugs) in your code significantly by just doing this:

```
else if(field.jsonName === "type") {
    var type = parseInt(quizValues.info.type, 10);

    if(type < 5) {
        $("#QuizType").val(type);
    } else {
        $("#QuizType").val(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: still not working, however interestingly enough this does work when executed from the console.  Keep in mind that I attached the type variable to the window object so I could access it from the console.

    `if(window.type < 5) {jQuery("#QuizType").val(window.type);}`

Comment: Did you `log` type from within the `else if` block to see what its value is?

Comment: yes I did, and it is logging with a value of 2.  But the actual value of the select box is not changing.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this was a bad question, a little more debugging reveals that at the point that my code is executed the quizType does not exist.  Not sure why but it's a start.